# Some kind of proxy to investigate requests

Tags: http-proxy

I need some kind of proxy which sits between client and server and simply dumps all request, but also forwards the requests to allow communication between client and server.

```
|--------|           |-------|           |--------|
| client |-----------| proxy |-----------| server |
|--------|           |-------|           |--------|
```

Reason I need this: I'm working on a client software and want to see how the (REST) requests actually are sent to the server. For example, I want to see the multipart POST entities, etc.

Off course I can use netcast to "emulate" the server, but this does not actually result in traffic going from client to server and vice versa. The ideal situation would be a proxy listening on port yyy which forwards all traffic from the client machine to host:yyy.

So my main question is: what kind of proxy am I looking for? Is it a forward proxy? Or a transparent proxy?

Comment: [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, you could be looking for the Fiddler HTTP proxy.

It is a web development tool that, when run will set itself up as a global proxy for your computer. It will show all http requests that your computer makes, with various options to inspect/replay/alter them.

You can get it at: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler